# mlr: what exactly does the function getBMRTuneResults?

Tags: mlr

I'm doing nested resampling with a 4x3 setup (4-fold cross-validation in the outer loop, and 3-fold cross-validation in the inner loop). For now, I only use Support Vector Machines (ksvm from kernlab). In the inner loop, I'm looking for the optimal tuning parameters C and sigma.

Calling getBMRPerformances() then outputs me the performances on the 4 individual outer test data sets. The function getBMRTuneResults() outputs 4 values for the measure I am using (in my case cohen's kappa) as well but they differ from the output of getBMRPerformances() and I don't understand what the second output actually is.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post the output you're referring to and code to reproduce it please?

Answer (score 1):

As the function name indicates, it outputs the results from tuning. So the performance values correspond to the performances calculated during the tuning (inner loop).

The four values in particular here are the performances reached by the best performing hyperparameter setting for a particular fold of your outer loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replay. Maybe I am missing something but since I am doing a 3-fold cross-validation in the inner loop, shouldn't I then get only 3 values instead of 4?

Comment: No. You are optimizing hyperparameters for 4 outer folds, hence you get back 4 tuning results. These will be used as hyperparameter settings in the outer loop to fit the model. In this case the number of folds of the inner loop does not matter.